# Caps Lock to RIGHT Control (It is important to be the right one)

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have found a lot of ways to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Left Control</kbd>. For example:
editing /etc/default/keyboard and adding "ctrl:nocaps" to the XKBOPTIONS

But I can't find anywhere how to map to <kbd>Right Control</kbd>, I need it to be the right because I am trying to do something after that and being the right is necessary for the next step

How can I map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Right Control</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
xev
```

And press the key Right Control. You will get an event like this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
root 0x266, subw 0x0, time 253995826, (1344,552), root:(1410,604),
state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Remember the keycode, in my case 105.

Create a script, for example /home/user/xmodmap.sh with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Caps_Lock"
```

Now give permissions to the script with:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/user/xmodmap.sh
```

And add it to be run when your Ubuntu starts going to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications and creating a new entry with the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 5 && /home/user/xmodmap.sh"
```

Comment: Why the "sleep 5"?

Comment: It is not working by the way. I have tried executing xmodmap with a file as argument whose content is: remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_R
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_R
add Control = Control_R
And it works if I execute it in a term, but it doesn't if I run it automatically at boot (neither with a sleep 5 before)

Comment: The reason for the sleep is better explained here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/644657/add-script-to-system-preferences-startup-applications

Comment: Have you tried a script like the example I gave? It works for me in Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 and 15.04... You might want to sleep for longer. Are you using Unity?

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work for me. It doesn't even work if I execute it in a term after booting. My machine is running Xubuntu 14.04 (XFCE + Ubuntu).

Comment: Mhhh... this is weird. Magically, now it works! Thank you, I don't know why it didn't work before in a term but I have reboot with sleep 10 and it has worked

Comment: Although now when the key is pressed it's like both keys are being pressed at the same time. How can I disable the other key?

Comment: Never mind. I have fix that by myself. Thank you again.